# Error with Mockito at Java unit test: Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm developing a unit test for my membership service class.
As usual, I mocked the respective repository and I'm trying to mock its method responses that are being used in my service

When I try to mock save or saveAndFlush methods from JPARepository, I'm getting the following error from Mockito:
[image]

Here's the method that I'm testing which belongs to RoleService
[image]

Here's my test routine:
[image]

Any help would be awesome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mockito is telling you it is expecting a specific `Role` instance while it's getting a different one. In your test, Mockito is expecting `roleRepository#save` to be called with `testingRole` as parameter, but the real object passed is `RoleDto.fromModel(testingRole)` which is a different one. Instead of using `testingRole` in the `when` clause, you could enter `Mockito.any(Role.class)`, or `RoleDto.fromModel(testingRole)` and it should work

Comment: This solved my friend. Gracias

Comment: I've added the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito is telling you it is expecting a specific `Role` instance while it's getting a different one. In your test, Mockito is expecting `roleRepository#save` to be called with `testingRole` as parameter, but the real object passed is `RoleDto.fromModel(testingRole)`, which is a different one. Instead of using `testingRole` in the `when` clause, you could enter `Mockito.any(Role.class)`, or `RoleDto.fromModel(testingRole)` and it should work